# How to transform table from list to boolean

Tags: postgresql, pivot

I have table like this in postgresql:

```
id | item1 | item2  |
1  | book  | pencil |
2  | book  | pencil |
3  | pen   | ruler  |
4  | book  | pen    |
```

then i want to change it into:

```
id  | book | pencil | pen | ruler |
1   | 1    | 1      | 0   | 0     |
2   | 1    | 1      | 0   | 0     |
3   | 0    | 0      | 1   | 1     |
4   | 1    | 0      | 1   | 0     |
```

which is 1 for true and 0 for false

now how is the query to transform it?

Comment: Can't you use single item column? (without using item1 and item2). Then it will be easier to write cross tab query.

Comment: @cha i can't because item1 and item2 means the different goods bought by the customer

Comment: I think you can improve table. Anyway I will add an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
id, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (t.item = 'book') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS book, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (t.item = 'pencil') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS pencil, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (t.item = 'pen') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS pen, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN (t.item = 'ruler') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS ruler
FROM 
(
SELECT id, item1 AS item FROM test_pivot AS  t1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT id, item2 AS item FROM test_pivot AS t2
) AS t
GROUP BY id
```